# MVC Controller View Javascript and passing values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that displays both the search screen and the results list. To start the results list is hidden.

On clicking the search button, instead of the view posting back to the controller using a Html.BeginForm, it has a JavaScript event handler which is called.

The Handler passes over a complex object, in the form of:

```
{ "searchData":
    { "ticketNumberCompare":0,
      "ticketSearchTextFrom":"0",
      "ticketSearchTextTo":null,
      "ticketDateCompare":1,
      "startDate":"2017-01-06T00:00:00",
      "endDate":"2017-01-13T00:00:00",
      ...
      etc
      ...
    },
  "searchMode":
    { "mode":2,
      "pageNumber":1,
      "pageSize":5,
      "sortDirection":"desc",
      ...
      etc
      ...
      "ValidationErrorMessages":null
    }
}
```

By using Json.Stringify, I have got the above structure to be converted for use by a function within the c# MVC 5 controller, defined as follows.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetSearchResultsJson(ComplexObject searchCriteria, int? page)
{

}
```

This function returns back html which is rendered from a Razor view using a model that contains the results from the database.

When I click on the submit button for the initial search all works and I get a partial view of five records displayed with the correct pageList values displayed.

When I click on the pageList items I get a page not found error.

On checking the ajax call for the initial load it is passing over the Json.Stringify of the structure at the top of this question. But the pageList items are not, they just pass over the page

Addendum:

Oh I forgot to mention that I have upgraded this function to use an object instead of the four string that used to be passed, because a new super search now has around 30 properties. Before the change the code worked fine.

Comment: what is the uri which you are using for posting with ajax? what is the structure of ComplexObject? and please post exception message as it is not clear what is actually happening

Comment: i think this is where the confusion is coming from. The ajax is calling: localhost:55152/Document/PAGE and attaching the Json via the data attribute. When the razor view is created it is creating links that are not calling ajax but are trying to call the controller directly using: localhost:55152/Document/PAGE?page=2

Comment: You have controller action created for page? It should accept the same search query object and page number. The action should search the data and return only the data belong to the specified page number.and it should return the same search result view. If you have this implemented then is should work fine.